# Range of conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ be a random variable with values in $A$.
Let $Y$ be random variable with values in $B$.

Let $g: A\times\mathbb R \to C$ a differentiable function.
Define $h(z)= \mathbb E(g(X,z)\mid Y=y)$.
Into which space is function $h$ mapping?

Comment: It looks like $h$ should depend on $y$ as well as $z$. Also, the output of $h$ is just a real number, so the answer to your question would be $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Since $g(x, z) \in C$ for every $x \in A, z \in \mathbb{R}$, therefore $E[g(X, z)] \in C$. We cannot refine this without giving more assumptions on $g$ and the distribution relationship between $X, Y$.